# Установил пакет Ninject.MVC.5 и все "поломал"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

Для своего учебного проекта я решил попробовать новый для меня пакет  `Ninject.MVC.5`. Я установил его в проект, написал вызов в контроллере:

```
IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IClientBaseRepo>().To<ClientBaseRepo>();
```

кстати, Framework 4.6.1

И получаю ошибку:

> Не удалось загрузить тип "Ninject.Infrastructure.IHaveKernel" из
>   сборки "Ninject, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7".

И вот стек, если поможет:

```
Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever.AssemblyChecker.GetAssemblyNames(IEnumerable`1 filenames, Predicate`1 filter)
   в Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever.GetAssemblyNames(IEnumerable`1 filenames, Predicate`1 filter)
   в Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 filenames)
   в Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader.LoadModules(IEnumerable`1 patterns)
   в Ninject.KernelConfiguration.Load(IEnumerable`1 filePatterns)
   в Ninject.KernelConfiguration..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules)
   в Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules)
   в Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules)
   в Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules)
   в mvc_CLientBase1.Controllers.ClientsController.Index() в D:\MVC\mvc_CLientBase1\mvc_CLientBase1\Controllers\ClientsController.cs:строка 22
   в System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   в System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   в System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   в System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Вряд ли он битый, наверное, я что-то не то сделал или пример "не из той оперы".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку?

Обучалку брал эту [вот](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level2/2_3.php)

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте установленные пакеты, согласованы ли они друг с другом. Не может ли так получиться, что Ninject.MVC5 у вас стоит 3й версии, а Ninject - 4й (т.е. беты). Если так оно и есть - надо поправить версии пакетов.

Если же с версиями пакетов все в порядке - возможно, у вас остались лишние файлы в папке bin от прошлых экспериментов. Почистите эту папку и соберите проект снова.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае проблема оказалась в том, что я создавал пустой веб-проект, и вручную наполнял его контроллерами и прочем содержимым.
Если бы я сразу проект типа MVC (галочку бы при создании проекта поставил), проблемы бы не возникло.